# Javascript Prototype side effects of the chain

Tags: javascript, prototype

This question is related of a book example. I tried to understand it , but at some point it confused me . 
In this example we created a constructor `function Ninja()` with one property `swung`. 
We created an object instance of that constructor with the name of ninja1 .
Then we add a method to the prototype of `Ninja()` constructor with the name of `swingSword()`.
Now if we check `ninja1.swingSword()` , we can access that method and everything its fine .

Now here we go , we set a new prototype object for `Ninja()` and set a method `pierce()` that returns true .

I notice two things so far. First is that `ninja1.swingSword()` can still access its "old" prototype . Second is that newly created objects from Ninja() constructor cant access `swingSword()` but they can access .pierce() method. 
My question is , why `ninja1` object cant access `pierce()` method ? Is still connected with its prototype to its constructor function which is `Ninja()`. I am posting the code to make things clear .

```js
function Ninja() {
  this.swung = true;
}

const ninja1 = new Ninja();

Ninja.prototype.swingSword = function() {
  return this.swung;
}

console.log(ninja1.swingSword());

Ninja.prototype = {
  pierce: function() {
    return true;
  }
}

console.log('ninj1 object can still use the old prototype even replacing old prototype with new object :' + ninja1.swingSword());


const ninja2 = new Ninja();

console.log(ninja2.pierce());
console.log(ninja1.pierce());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have changed the whole `prototype` object, so it is now has only the `pierce` function. But the previously defined object - `ninja1` still has a reference to the previous `prototype`

```
Ninja.prototype ---> |--------------|
                     | Swing Swords | 
                     |--------------|

                           ^
                           | prototype

ninja1 ------------> |its properties|
```

And when you change the prototype it is now looked like

```
                     |--------------|
                     | Swing Swords | 
                     |--------------|

                           ^
                           | prototype

ninja1 ------------> |its properties| 


Ninja.prototype ---> |--------|
                     | pierce | 
                     |--------|

                          ^
                          | prototype

ninja2 ----------> |its properties|
```

You can see that `ninja1` still contains reference to the old prototype object and has nothing with the new prototype. But `ninja2` has to the newer prototype object.

Comment: Yes, ninja1 shouldnt be able to access the new prototype object and pierce function ?

Comment: Look at the pictures. I tried to show you the references of the `ninja`

Comment: oh i thought that ninja1 would still be able to access its "old" prototype but it would be able to access to the new as well.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of a constructor function, a **proto** link is made in that object which refer to the prototype of constructor, so adding any properties or method on prototype won't change the link or reference but when you define a new prototype the constructor will have an new reference for prototype object and hence the instances created after the change will refer to new prototype but the older ones still refers to the old object as **proto** is still refers to links to the old prototype object.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to understand exactly what's going on under the hood. Here's what happens when you call a function with the `new` keyword, complete with pseudocode:

1. A new object is created with properties linking it to the constructor and the constructor's `prototype` property *at the time it was created*:

   ```js
   var newObj = {
       constructor: Ninja,
       __proto__: Ninja.prototype // = { swingSword: function() { ... } }
   };
   ```
2. The constructor function is called with its `this` context assigned to the new object and any arguments passed.

   ```js
   var returned = Ninja.call(newObj, ...arguments); // In your case, no arguments
   ```
3. If the constructor returns undefined, the new object bound to `this` becomes the instance value—complete with any properties you added in the constructor.

   ```js
   var instance = typeof returned === 'undefined' ? newObj : returned;
   ```

The first time you call `new Ninja()`, you get back an object with a `__proto__` property referencing the original value of `Ninja.prototype`. This `__proto__` property is what handles the prototype chain. (See explanation below.)

When you change the value of `Ninja.prototype`, the object you just created *still references the old value* as its prototype; its `__proto__` property hasn't changed. It will still delegate to properties on the old prototype. However, if you call `new Ninja()` again, you get an object whose `__proto__` property references the updated prototype.

### Sidenote: what is `__proto__`?

`__proto__` is a bit naughty.

The EcmaScript specification states that every object should have a `[[Prototype]]` property which is a reference to its prototype.

The weird name comes about because it's a *specification property*—something the spec defines for convenience, but which actual implementations don't need to expose. It only exists as a compact way for the specification to describe how the prototype chain works.

However, early JS engines started exposing access to this internal `[[Prototype]]` property as `__proto__`. This practise became sufficiently widespread that the ES2015 spec now explicitly defines it, albeit marked as a legacy feature.